# Google Or-Tools Routing - Solution is null

Tags: c#, matrix, or-tools

I am trying to implement VRPTW of Google OR-Tools. But I am facing an issue. When I pass the dynamic Time matrix then the solution object is null but when I pass the Time matrix which is given in example then it worked.

Here is my code

```
 public class DataModel
    {
        public long[,] DistanceMatrix { get; set; }
        public long[,] TimeMatrix = {
            //commented matrix is dynamic generated
  // {0,5,20,10,0,5},  
  //{5,0,25,10,5,5},
  //{20,25,0,30,20,20},
  //{10,10,30,0,10,15},
  //{0,5,20,10,0,5},
  //{5,5,20,15,5,0},
    {0, 6, 9, 8, 7, 3},
  {6, 0, 8, 3, 2, 6},
  {9, 8, 0, 11, 10, 6},
  {8, 3, 11, 0, 1, 7},
  {7, 2, 10, 1, 0, 6},
  {3, 6, 6, 7, 6, 0},
};
        public long[,] TimeWindows = {
  {0, 5},    // depot
  {7, 12},   // 1
  {10, 15},  // 2
  {16, 18},  // 3
  {10, 13},  // 4
  {0, 5},    // 5
};
        public int VehicleNumber = 3;
        public int Depot = 0;
    };
```

Here is the main function code

```
DataModel data = new DataModel();
            // data.TimeMatrix = TimeMatrix;
            // Create Routing Index Manager
            RoutingIndexManager manager = new RoutingIndexManager(
                data.TimeMatrix.GetLength(0),
                data.VehicleNumber,
                data.Depot);

            // Create a Routing Model.
            RoutingModel routing = new RoutingModel(manager);

            // Create and register a transit callback.
            int transitCallbackIndex = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(
                (long fromIndex, long toIndex) =>
                {
                    // Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
                    var fromNode = manager.IndexToNode(fromIndex);
                    var toNode = manager.IndexToNode(toIndex);
                    return data.TimeMatrix[fromNode, toNode];
                }
                );

            // Define the cost of each arc.
            routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transitCallbackIndex);

            // Add Distance constraint.
            routing.AddDimension(
                transitCallbackIndex, // transit callback
                30, // allow waiting time
                30, // vehicle maximum capacities
                false,  // start cumul to zero
                "Time");
            RoutingDimension timeDimension = routing.GetMutableDimension("Time");
            // Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
            for (int i = 1; i < data.TimeWindows.GetLength(0); ++i)
            {
                long index = manager.NodeToIndex(i);
                timeDimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
                    data.TimeWindows[i, 0],
                    data.TimeWindows[i, 1]);
            }
            // Add time window constraints for each vehicle start node.
            for (int i = 0; i < data.VehicleNumber; ++i)
            {
                long index = routing.Start(i);
                timeDimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
                    data.TimeWindows[0, 0],
                    data.TimeWindows[0, 1]);
            }

            // Instantiate route start and end times to produce feasible times.
            for (int i = 0; i < data.VehicleNumber; ++i)
            {
                routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
                    timeDimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)));
                routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
                    timeDimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)));
            }

            // Setting first solution heuristic.
            RoutingSearchParameters searchParameters =
              operations_research_constraint_solver.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters();
            searchParameters.FirstSolutionStrategy =
              FirstSolutionStrategy.Types.Value.PathCheapestArc;

            // Solve the problem.
            Assignment solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(searchParameters);  //it is null when dynamic time matrix is used, but it is not null when time matrix mentioned in example is used.
```

The problem seems to be in AddDimension Method. I am struck in this but could not find any solution. Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is null indicates that the solver was not able to find any feasible solution. Most likely your time windows are too tight.

Either try relaxing your time windows

or make sure nodes are optional (using addDisjunction).

Comment: Yes the problem was with time window. What does actually time window mean? Is it time duration in minutes like time window for location 1 is (7,11), that means driver should reach to location 1 within 7 to 11 minutes?

Comment: You decide what is a time unit.  Having a unit time of 1 minutes is a reasonable choice. The solver is completely agnostic and only understands positive integers, whatever their semantics.

Comment: Can i ask one more question? How can i get length of route for each vehicle? Actually i have to limit 2 routes for each vehicle. Is it possible? If yes then how?

Comment: You need to unroll each route. See the printing functions in the code samples.